# Back button on WP8.1

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, onbackpressed

I try to add code to Hardware Back Button on WP8.1

```
Private Sub onBackPressed(sender As Object, e As BackPressedEventArgs)

    some code

End Sub
```

But when I press Back - my app just closes.
onBackPressed event is not happening at all, how can I fixed it?

Comment: This might helpp you  https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/290680/check-browser-back-button-click

Comment: Sorry, this link is not about WP8, is about Windows Forms

Answer (score 0):

Did you register for that event?
You need to first add this youself

HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed; ( sorry c# )

cfr http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/backbutton-handling-with-winprt-and-windows-phone-8-1-wpdev/

Comment: What you mean by "register"? It is like declaration?

Comment: I have xmlns:BackKeyPress="onBackKeyPress" in my XAML is it correct?

Comment: Not sure about VB.net, but you do have to hook up the HardwareButtons.BackPressed event to your onBackPressed method! In C# we do this in the App.xaml.cs ( code behind App.xaml )

Comment: yes, in VB is the same in App.xaml.vb, I have declared it there, but in some reason is doesn't work. Thank you for your help. I will investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

I know that for C# its easy.
Add this to the constructor:

```
HardwareButtons.BackPressed += this.Hardware_BackButton_Pressed;
```

And use:

```
    public void Hardware_BackButton_Pressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do things here..
    }
```